# How could threads in a threadgroup work together?

Tags: metal

In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/about_threads_and_threadgroups?language=objc) of thread groups, it says "`Threads` are organized into `threadgroups` that are executed together and can share a common block of memory. While sometimes kernel functions are designed so that threads run independently of each other, `it's also common for threads in a threadgroup to collaborate on their working set.`"

For now, I have only worked on some GPGPU programs which have threads working on their own purpose. Could someone give me an example, how `threads` in `threadgroup` can work together? How could they use the shared memory to collaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with threadgroups is that they work on SIMD like data sets. You execute 1 instruction and it operates on multiple data elements. There are special Metal instructions where threads in a threadgroup can pass results to other threads, but those only exist for MacOSX implementation and not iOS. But there is another kind of "working together" that is possible with a compute shader. If you want to see an example of an advanced Metal based Rice decoder that uses a compute shader to operated on multiple input elements and then emit multiple output elements, take a look at my Rice decoder [Rice decoder for Metal](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post23_metal_rice/). This code basically operates byte by byte and decompresses data, but the reads are done 4 bytes at a time so that SIMD execution results the best possible performance.

Comment: Just a small note: threads in a threadgroup *can* pass results to other threads in that same threadgroup by using threadgroup memory (also on iOS). But they can't communicate across threadgroups.